# Shell variable passed to -d option of curl not working correctly

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am trying to use PATCH method in CURL command use -d option. my code is like below: 
    IFS=" "; 
    while read line
    do
      array=($line);
      json_string="{ \"attributes\": { \"member_id\": ${array[0]}, \"is_student\":  ${array[1]} }}"

```
  curl -v --fail --silent --show-error --request PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --user $API_KEY:$API_SECRET -d $json_string $PROFILE_URL/${array[0]} --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
done < $file
```

the input file is txt file which has two columns:
123 0 
I am using **space** as a line separator. 
The problem is when I use $json_string I get this error:

```
    == Info: Rebuilt URL to: "attributes":/
    == Info: Could not resolve host: "attributes"
    == Info: Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "attributes"
    curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
    == Info: Rebuilt URL to: "member_id":/
    == Info: Could not resolve host: "membe

r_id"
== Info: Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "member_id"
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: 123,/
== Info: Could not resolve host: 123,
```

and

```
=> Send data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: "{
== Info: upload completely sent off: 2 out of 2 bytes
```

but when I use "$json_string" ($json_string surrounded with double quote) it works fine. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your variable `json_string` in double quotes to prevent word splitting by shell:

```
curl -v --fail --silent --show-error --request PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json"  --user "$API_KEY:$API_SECRET" -d "$json_string" "$PROFILE_URL/${array[0]}" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

You can read the line directly into your array this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a line; do
  # your logic
done < "$file"
```

Read more about word spitting here: [Bash Best Practices - Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)

Comment: I know it works when I surround the variable with quotes. but why is it necessary? I already use double quote when defining $json_string.

Comment: If you don't enclose your variable in double quotes, shell will interpret whitespaces and wildcard characters if any.  The result would be that your `curl` command will get the words in `json_string` as separate arguments, instead of a single string.

Comment: @sia - please see the updated answer - I have added a link for more info on word spitting.

Comment: thanks @codeforester. that link was helpful. it was because I was using " " as IFS. when I changed my delimiter to "|" then the code works even without ". but I don't know why my question is downvoted